# How to plot percentage value from absolute value in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I have this dataframe

```
dput(C_Em_2000_Lat_Am)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L
), .Label = c("Crop Agriculture", "Mining", "Mixed Agriculture", 
"Other land use", "Pasture", "Tree crops", "Urban", "Water"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Emission Factor", class = "factor"), 
    V3 = c(97004.1719086906, 10899.1747511239, 938738.864637841, 
    11024.7872260286, 129805.568347205, 778.178352715695, 28603.3785457348, 
    24333.5577048119)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot the percentage values of the column V3 which are currently absolute values. So far I have managed to plot the absolute values (see below) but also need to plot the percentage of each values (where total value = sum of values in column V3).

```
ggplot(C_Em_2000_Lat_Am, aes(x=V1, y = V3)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity", binwidth = 0.1)+
  labs(x = "", y = "Carbon Emissions (T/year)") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),axis.title=element_text(size=20), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=20, face='bold'),legend.text=element_text(size=20), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_fill_grey("grey50") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1000000))
```

Can someone help me out with that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
ggplot(C_Em_2000_Lat_Am, aes(x=C_Em_2000_Lat_Am$V1, y = (C_Em_2000_Lat_Am$V3)/sum(C_Em_2000_Lat_Am$V3))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1))+
  labs(x = "", y = "Carbon Emissions (%)") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),axis.title=element_text(size=20), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=20, face='bold'),legend.text=element_text(size=20), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + scale_fill_grey("grey50")
```